# How do you compile dependencies manually? Cygwin

Tags: dependencies

I installed cygwin on windows and the setup.exe doesnt include all the dependencies.
in the folder however, there are many dependencies that arent included in the setup.exe.

when i type in a dependency in the search bar at the top left corner, it doesnt appear, but it IS in the cygwin folder.

[image]
[image]

is there a way to ammend/add/update dependencies manually, after cygwin has been installed?

how would i do this?

Comment: can you provide an example? maybe a screen shot?

Comment: @RedCricket I added screen shots! :)

Comment: OpenSSL's libcapi is not its own cygwin package, that's why its not showing in "Select Packages". Try searching for "ssl" instead.

Comment: @derobert, do you have an email or somewhere we could chat? please?  ive been having trouble getting cygwin to work for days now and im going nuts

Comment: @thisisjnd Unfortunately, you need 20 rep on the site to chat. I tried to create a room to explicitly let you in, but it appears only a diamond-mod can do that. Anyway, I honestly haven't used cygwin in almost a decade. Other than trying to help you find the OpenSSL development package in the cygwin installer, I'm not sure what else to try. If you want to find it in the installer, search for ssl. And make sure to tell it to install development headers.

Comment: @derobert could we pass eachother's skype address?  or place a link to some quick chat website?  searching for ssl was the first thing i did. when i kept getting the error i went back and ticked off literally all the boxes.

Comment: Do you have `/usr/include/openssl` (as seen from inside cygwin, e.g., with `ls`) Should have a bunch of `.h` files there. If so, you have the openssl-devel package installed... and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: @deorobert yup, that file is there, with a bunch of `.h` files. that means it's installed.. but i still get that error?  weird, idk..  anyway, someone else suggested i try kali with vmware player so im going to try that out.  thanks again though!

Answer (score 1):

When trying to solve problems like this, the [Cygwin Package Search](http://cygwin.com/packages/) is your friend. In this specific case, it tells you that you want to install [`libopenssl100`](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Flibopenssl100%2Flibopenssl100-1.0.1g-1&grep=libcapi).

The Cygwin `setup.exe` built-in search didn't find this because it only searches package file names and the description text. It does not search through the names of files *included* in the packages as the above web search engine does. To do that, you'd have to balloon the current `setup.ini` file size with a complete file name index, which would slow the search and slow the startup of `setup.exe` considerably.

Some Cygwin packages do a better job of listing the components within the package in their long description text, so the built-in search does sometimes turn up such internal package details. There is no [rule](http://cygwin.com/setup.html) saying you have to do that, though.

More generally, it is not the case that there are dependencies in Cygwin that you have to compile by hand. The people who control what packages go into Cygwin won't allow a package maintainer to provide such a half-baked package.

You may find *outdated* packages in Cygwin, but the versions available should at least be *consistent* in that all the pieces you need to run the software as-packaged are present in the repository.